# LMR10510 - Simple switcher "breakoutboard" output measures 0V

Tags: pcb, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, texas-instruments

I have a problem concerning this Simple Switcher found [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr10510.pdf). I used the design example 3 for the LMR10510Y found on page 17 of the datasheet, however measuring the output pins of the switcher returns 0V on the Feedback and SW Pin. VIN receives 5V and EN is around 2.0XV. Here is a picture of my schematics and the board layout (I considered the layout considerations found in the datasheet): [image]

Any Ideas what went wrong? If the question is too broad please ask!

Comment: Is Diode possibly backwards?  Do you have a load attached?

Comment: In this schematic it appears that D1 is across pins 1 and 2 of your chip. In this layout it appears that D1 is connected to pin 3 of the chip, and I don't see anything connected to pin 2 of the chip. Something got mirrored or left out or both?

Comment: @davidcary Yes, you are right. I changed the layout in the mean time and now I measure 0.8V at the out pin. However 3.3V were to expect, do you happen to know what went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've used the wrong pin-out for the device. The pin-out you've used is (somehow) partly for the WSON package but you've got a SOT-23 on the PCB: -

[image]

On your PCB you have pin 1 connected as if it were the FB pin yet, for a SOT-23 pin 1 is SW etc...

You also don't appear to have GND (pin 2) connected (I've highlighted it in green): -

[image]

Comment: My hero! You checked his pinout!

Comment: @Andy I changed the layout and now I get an output of 0.8V at my pinout, expected were 3.3V, do you happen to know what went wrong again?

Comment: Check the resistor values and the diode placement.

Comment: @Andy Alright, will do! Thanks so far ;). I need to work a lot next week, if I won't be able to resolve the problem I will open another discussion. Have a nice weekend!